# Any way to set per-solution color options (VS2010)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to configure VS2010 to use different color schemes for different solutions?  On the Macintosh, in the 1990's, I could add wctb resources to documents so they would open with different color schemes.  This made it easier to find the right window to click, and also helped avoid accidentally typing something into the wrong document (otherwise easy to do if one has several similar documents open).  Is there any nice way to achieve a similar effect in VS2010?  I'd mainly like to change the text background color and window background color.

When I was using vs2005 and vbEx2005, I could set vbEx to one scheme and vs to another, but right now I'm using vs2010 for everything.  Is there any nice way to set colors on a per-project basis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not without writing some code.  As Jared has already mentioned, the colors you want to change are part of the VS-level settings.  However, it would be possible to author a VS extension (or even just a macro) that would toggle the settings to solution-specific preferences when a solution is opened.

Comment: By the way, did I ever thank you for setting me on the right path?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a nice way of doing it.  Select "Macro IDE...", then open up "EnvironmentEvents" and add the following after the "Automatically generated code" region:

```
    Sub handleColorSettings() Handles SolutionEvents.opened, DocumentEvents.documentopening
        Dim myColor As UInt32
        myColor = &HC0FFFF
        Try
            myColor = UInt32.Parse(IO.File.ReadAllText(DTE.Solution.FullName & ".bgcolor.txt"), Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        CType(DTE.Properties("FontsAndColors", "TextEditor").Item("FontsAndColorsItems").Object, EnvDTE.FontsAndColorsItems).Item("Plain Text").Background = myColor
    End Sub
```

Any time a project is opened, or a file is opened within a project, the system will look for a file with the name "(fullSolutionName).bgcolor.txt".  If, e.g., the solution is "myThing.sln", the file used will be "myThing.sln.bgcolor.txt".  If such a file is found and it contains a valid hex number, that will be used as the background color.  Otherwise, a default color (&hC0FFFF above, but easily changeable) will be used.

Comment: Great solution. I got it to work with one small enhancement (added `Or Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite Or Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite` to make it tolerant of whitespace). By way of documentation, the hex value in the file does not need any sort of prefix, e.g. "F0D0C0" works.

Comment: @Matt Curtis : Being a more or less newbie at VS macros, could you add the full path to where the macro goes.  I tried Tools->Macros...->Macro-IDE->(class view)MyMacros->EnvironmentEvents but that didn't seem to work.  And just where were the Globalization lines added?  Many thanks!

Comment: @WesMiller I think I just followed the instructions at the top of supercat's answer here. I can't remember the details but I think that worked for me (using VS2010, it might have shifted around in a different version.)

Comment: @MattCurtis  Finally got it working. Turns out there were build errors in MyMacros RecordModule.  Finally got those fixed and then had a LONG fight to find out that I had to put the filename in a string instead of directly in the IO.File.ReadAllText.  No idea why.  I have a drive letter, X;, mapped to my VS2008\Projects directory.  Tried using the real C:.....\VS2008\Projects\.... filename as a string in the ReadAllText() and that didn't work either.  Maybe something to do with spaces in the path?  Anyway, assigning the path to a string var fixed it.

Comment: @MattCurtis - Also, am I correct that the color string in the bgcolor file is BGR, not RGB.  0000FF gets me a solid red background.

Comment: @WesMiller: The color string is interpreted as a single integer, instead of being parsed as three bytes.  Colors as integers have the least-significant word as read, probably as a consequence of Intel processors using LSB-first byte order.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your Visual Studio as a different user and choose different color scheme per each user.
First, you need to create a local user with administrator privileges.
Then, Right click + Shift on Visual Studio -> Run as different user and enter the user you created and password.
If you want to run your Visual Studio as a different user via Batch file, You can use the "runas" command or download "psexec" tool.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Colors are maintained on a per Visual Studio instance basis.  There is no way to customize them any a finer granularity such as the project level.

Comment: Would there be any way to set up an auto-start macro to configure the colors based on the currently-loaded project?  My understanding is that macros can be set up to do a lot of things, though I have no idea how one would determine which macro commands to use for such purposes.

Comment: @Nicole Calinoiu: Check out my solution above.